# MongoDB - Get the year from timestamp date

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is what my sample data looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60662c4cbcd96707a8ba8fa7"),
    "createdAt" : NumberInt(1617308748),
    "email" : "abc.com",
    "score" : NumberInt(50),
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60662c4cbcd96707a8ba8fa7"),
    "createdAt" : NumberInt(1617308748),
    "email" : "abc.com",
    "score" : NumberInt(50),
    "year" : NumberInt(2021),
}
```

What can I use,
Right now I am using `$toDate` to convert it into ISO date and then using `$year` in the project stage to get the year but that solution is failing. Help me with the query.

Comment: It seems you need to convert the int to long type, then perform the `$toDate`. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JNnpUHFN_hj)

Comment: Even then my date has been set from 1970. Do I need to multiply my number into 1000

Comment: Yes. When cast long to date, $toDate take the value as millisecond. [Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#behavior)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$toDate` operator can take the value with `long` type to Date. From the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#behavior),

> Returns a date that corresponds to the number of milliseconds represented by the long value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      email: 1,
      score: 1,
      year: {
        $year: {
          $toDate: {
            $multiply: [
              "$createdAt",
              1000
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```